# How would we explain a whirlpool shape without using centrifugal forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, centripetal-force, vortex

How would we explain a whirlpool shape formed in a bucket without using fictitious forces like centrifugal force? I am in high school and my teacher always gave me the explanation for shape of whirlpool that the "centrifugal force" pushes the liquid outwards(towards the edges of bucket) but it isn't a real force right? What if I want to explain it form earth's frame of reference and not the rotating frame? How would I explain it? What is causing this movement of water towards the edges ,causing it to rise up and generate higher pressure towards the edges?

Comment: [Liquid mirror telescope!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-mirror_telescope#Explanation_of_the_equilibrium)

Comment: @Farcher that's a better starter problem, since it has uniform vorticity and a static (in one frame) analytic solution. A whirlpool is far more complicated, with a core of vorticity, surrounded by irrotational flow.

Answer (score 1):

Each little bit of liquid parcel on the surface is going around in a circle. To do that, there must be a force that is providing it with centripetal acceleration. This force must be coming from the gradient of the liquid surface, the height of which determines the gravitationally induced pressure, or else there would not be a way to maintain the circular motion.

If you want to talk about the movement of water towards the edges, the relevant concept is inertia.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how it gets set up in the first place. I know how it maintains itself due to pressure difference which provides centripetal forces for each parcel of water.

Comment: That is what the last statement is separated out for. When you first start it rotating, inertia flings the liquid parcels outwards, setting up the pressure needed to pile them up, creating the height difference.

Comment: But how I can't imagine, suppose we have a bucket with round curvature, we start rotatingi it, now we look at the parcel near edge, it will also rotate because of friction between bucket and water, similar thing is happening to all parcel, I don't see them piling up at the edges and causing higher pressure?? Like I can imagine thing ina centrifuge but not here

Comment: But they do, it just takes longer for the water to start moving fast enough to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The water at the outer edge of the bucket wants to travel in a straight line.  It can't, and smashes into the wall of the bucket. It gets compressed and its pressure rises.  The pressure rise forces the water up the sides of the bucket  making the depth greater.

Same happens for water not in direct contact with the wall, except that it smashes into other water molecules.  The speed of the inner water is less and, consequently, the water rises less.  So a curved surface is formed.

The varying depth of the water causes a pressure gradient - higher pressure at larger radii.  This pressure gradient causes a centripetal force toward the center of the bucket which keeps the water moving in a circle.

You are correct - there is no centrifugal force pushing the water outward.